# How does one bypass the iCloud lock on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, apple-id, authentication, activation-lock

I bought a MacBook Air from someone, and they didn't properly factory reset it. I am currently trying to reset it, but when going to Recovery mode via the Internet to proceed further, it requires the person's Apple ID.

So far I've tried to get in contact with the person, but they no longer respond. Is there any course of action other than selling it for parts as it’s still in perfect working order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how does one bypass iCloud lock on MacBook

#### You don’t.

This feature was designed to *secure* your device from nefarious actors.  If you could easily bypass this lock, it wouldn’t be of any value.

> I bought a MacBook Air from someone and they didn't properly factory reset… so far I've tried to get in contact with the person to no success they no longer respond…

This MacBook Air is probably stolen.  A legitimate seller would work with you to un-authorize the device from their iCloud account before selling. Even post sale, there would be no issue in responding to you - it’s a super simple process to sign out of a device.

> any course of action other than selling for parts as its still in perfect working order.

Unfortunately, no.  You’ve got an expensive paper weight on your hands now.

#### Going Forward…

This will be an expensive lesson to learn.  However, going forward, [use the checklist that Apple provides for transferring  ownership](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065) as a “buyers’ checklist” of sorts.  Don’t accept possession (don’t let money change hands) until these things are complete.

As for the device, you might be able to sell it for parts, but you could also report this to your local authorities.  If you transferred money via app, there may be an electronic paper trail they could use to identify the sellers. I’m not saying this will be successful by any means, but you won’t know until you try.

Besides, if [Find My is activated on that device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208987), the original user could ping your location and you’d technically be in possession of stolen property.  That’s not a good scenario to find yourself in.

Comment: True I'm just trying to exaust options before I think about selling for parts

Comment: originally they did help me, and I was able to use it. but upgraded and no longer needed it so was selling myself then found that it was still connected to his account.

Comment: See the link in the last paragraph about Activation Lock.  It can be disabled via the web by the original owner.  Not much of an issue to do so.

Comment: okay, ill keep trying to contact any thoughts on this zero day I saw for intel based Macs that lets you bypass to login couple years old already probably patched

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, that has to do with the VPro nonsense in Intel chips.  It basically allows you to control the computer as if sitting in front of it, but remotely.  Since you can’t get in, neither will the exploit.

Comment: ahh okay noted, thanks!

Comment: Why is everyone assuming "stolen" when "part of a consignment sold by-weight by company or household liquidators or recyclers/remarketers" is as least as likely a source of IT equipment that has no longer any connection to the original owner, especially (no information given by OP on that) with equipment >3 years old (corporate refresh cycles)...

Comment: Legitimate sellers don’t ghost you, @rackandboneman

Comment: @Allan if - and yes, only if - it was indeed sold wholesale as an "as is!" or "defective" item, a seller might behave that way without there being a problem with the legitimacy of the goods - merely out of an attitude of "told them as-is, so since they must be deaf, no point discussing with them". If that was a facebook marketplace, craigslist or such sale... then yes, 100% agreed.